# Analysis of loss curve : raw data VS normalized data (Machine learning / Keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, normalization, loss-function

I'm trying to configure my CNN, and this need to analyze loss function results. I'm working with à VGG-16 (CNN). Input data are grey scaled images. So each pixel have a value of [0:255].

For the first part, I substracted the mean : pixel - 127 to have for each image a range of [-127:128]. Here are a loss / accuracy result with this configuration :

[image] [image]

In this case there are some noise at the beginning (epoch 0 to 25), so I thought that it could be resolved by normalizing data.

So I change each pixel with : (pixel - 127)/128 to normalize in an easy way first. Here are for the same configuration the curves :

[image]
[image]

The noise disappear but now, the train curve have a behaviour I never met before.. Could somenone said to me if the behaviour is usual and why ? And I would like to know if you know a good way to analyze these kind of curves.

Thanks you

Comment: What set of hyperparameters are you using? Also it's more common to normalize dividing by 255.0 to get a float type

Comment: In this case it is a learning rate of 10-3, a batch of 1024, and Relu activation function

Comment: Do you have a data leak between train/validation sets ?

Comment: I'm working with indexes so each elements of train and validation sets are defined by an index before the train and my data_generator associate each index to each element so I don't think so. I will implement the decay in my Optimizer (Adam) and see if I have better results, I will post results here !

Answer (score 2):

Well it looks as if you  are reaching convergence very fast and you are jumping out of your minima. Try lowering the learning rate, put decay on your LR or do an early stop.

Also it might be interesting to do K-folding. It might be that your training set has 'hard samples' that are not in your test set and are creating those spikes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I will try to put decay on LR. This may resolve problem of "noise" that I can observe in the first loss plot ? Plus, I ever work with K-fold, this plot represent 1 of my 5 loss results. These plots are done with my validation set, so it's a part of my training set (so there are not supposed to be as far from the train set)

Comment: What do you think about the decay parameter for Adam optimzer ?

Comment: Your validation set is part of your training set? that's no good.

Comment: Yeah, use that parameter of the Adam optimizer. Might help to stabilize the curve

Comment: I wasn't clear, I do a k-fold cross val, si I split my dataset into 2 part : train and test, and then I split the train part into val and final_train, so I train the model with final_train and compute the loss with the val part ;)

Comment: Alright! Keep me updated, I am interested haha

Comment: So the decay parameters leads to have a smoother curve, but this parameters changes the LR every epochs so it could be very very long to converge. I think that a better way to do it is by change the LR when a plate appear.. ! Anyway, my strange behavious is still here !

Comment: Something more sophisticated as you propose sounds like a good idea. Although I think that the accuracy you achieved is going to be hard to get better. Why do you think you have not reached convergence?

Comment: My problem wasn't about accuracy, it is about the strange behaviour of the loss curve beetween epoch 0 and 25. If I decrease LR, I think I can't reach convergence because even if I compute 3000 epochs, the curve is still decreasing

Comment: What I mean is that given the accuracy you have, trying to minimize that loss might no be worth it. Around epoch 250 you have and increase in validation loss, this might be overfitting...